# Knowing that P(B) = P(B') and P(A|B) + P(A|B') = 3/4 find P(A)

Tags: probability-theory

A, B are in the same sample space. 
My attempt to solve this problem: 
$$P(B) = 1-P(B) \Rightarrow P(B) = 0.5$$ $$P(A|B) = \frac{P(A\cap B)}{0.5}$$ 
$$P(A|B') = \frac{P(A \cap B')}{0.5}$$
$$P(A \cap B') = P(A) - P(A\cap B)$$
$$2P(A\cap B) + 2P(A) - 2P(A\cap B)= \frac{3}{4}$$
$$P(A) = \frac{3}{8}$$ 
Could you tell me if this is a correct way to solve this?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is correct. We could also use the [law of total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability) to obtain a little clearer solution. We have that
$$
P(A)=P(A\mid B)P(B)+P(A\mid B')P(B')=[P(A\mid B)+P(A\mid B')]\cdot1/2=3/4\cdot1/2=3/8
$$
since $P(B)=P(B')=1/2$.